# How to style last row of Gridview text into Bold in c#?

Tags: gridview, background-color

I can't to style last row of **Gridview** text into **Bold**.

With this code on **RowDataBound** event I can give a different background color on last row of **Gridview**.

How to style last row of **Gridview** text into **Bold** ?

[image]

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (((string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "sName")).Equals("TOT"))
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            e.Row.Font.Bold = true;
            e.Row.Font.Italic = true;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: is last row is footer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PreRender event for styling the row and use `grdAlert.Rows[GridView1.Rows.Count - 1]` to find last row:

```
protected void GridView_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow LastRow = grdAlert.Rows[GridView1.Rows.Count - 1];

    LastRow.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
    LastRow.Font.Bold = true;
    LastRow.Font.Italic = true;
}
```